# If I change the Charset can i use ' instead of ` for delimitating a field?

Tags: mysql, delimiter, character-encoding

Instead of having this:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `address` (
   `Contact_ID` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key',
   `Street Address` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `City` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Zip Code` char(8) DEFAULT NULL,
   `Country` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Contact_ID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Moradas';
```

I Want to be able to do this instead:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'address' (
   'Contact_ID' smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT ´0´ COMMENT ´Primary Key´,
   'Street Address' char(50) DEFAULT NULL, (...)
```

I'm doing this on WAMPSERVER. This is because it's really not practical at all having to do 'shift+character' in order to produce the ` everytime I create a table and populate it.

Comment: On most keyboards there's no shift for doing a backtick... Mine is just left from the 1 button above the letters

Comment: You only *need* to quote your identifiers with backticks if they contain [special characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html).  Avoid special characters in your identifier names and you can omit the backticks altogether.

Comment: Unfortunnatly, such doensn't happen on mine. :| But is there a way to change the MySQL definitions on WAMPSERVER? Or does it have to do with the charset? If so, which one should I use? I am using utf8

Comment: @eggyal Special characters or spaces, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Upgrading to an answer*)

As explained in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/identifiers.html), identifiers can be unquoted if they comprise only certain characters:

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>
> - ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)
> - Extended: U+0080 .. U+FFFF

Also, note that the manual goes on to explain:

> If the [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:
>
> ```
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...
> mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
> mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> The [`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode causes the server to interpret double-quoted strings as identifiers. Consequently, when this mode is enabled, string literals must be enclosed within single quotation marks. They cannot be enclosed within double quotation marks. The server SQL mode is controlled as described in [Section 5.1.6, “Server SQL Modes”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-sql-mode.html).

Comment: Thank you! Now I only have to figure out how to do that within WAMPSERVER. :)